# How to style header toolbar and footer/pagination toolbar separately?

Tags: reactjs, mui-datatable

I am trying to style the pagination toolbar, in the footer, but it seems to be taking on the styles of the header toolbar. I would like the pagination toolbar background to be white with black text, but this is what I am getting. Where am I going wrong, how do I fix this?

[image]

```
overrides: {
    MUIDataTableBodyRow: {
        root: {
        '&:nth-child(odd)': { 
            backgroundColor: '#eee'
        },
        '&:nth-child(even)': { 
            backgroundColor: '#f8f8f8'
        }
        },
    },
    MUIDataTableToolbar: {
        icon: {
        color: "white",
        '&:hover': {
                color: "#eee"
            }
        },
    },
    MuiToolbar: {
        root: {
            /* toolbar with icons */
            backgroundColor: '#039be5',
            color: 'white'
        },
    },
    MuiTableCell: {
        head: {
            /* header row */
            backgroundColor: '#81d4fa !important',
            color: 'white !important'
        }
    },
    MUIDataTableSelectCell: {
        headerCell: {}
    },
    MUIDataTableHeadCell: {
        fixedHeaderCommon: {}
    },
    MuiTableFooter: {
        root: {
            '& .MuiToolbar-root': {
                backgroundColor: 'white !important',
            },
        },
    },
}
```